# How to replace " in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, replace

Simple! How to replace " in .NET with something...?

Comment: The quote character? In a string?

Comment: there is no " in .NET, only ., N, E and T.
Try searching for the .NET string manipulations functions in google.

Comment: How to replace '' with what, exactly? Please elucidate.

Comment: Replace in what, by what? Voting to close as NARQ.

Comment: @Adrian: Please ask clear questions, don't post just scraps.

Comment: @Adrian: And somehow I think your first comment is going to be "But that's C#, not VB"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string newValue = "quote \"here\"".Replace("\"", "'");
```

Or

```
string newValue = @"quote ""here""".Replace(@"""", "'");
```

Comment: Probably should be `@"""""`. That sure is ugly.

Comment: @Kobi: 5 quotes wouldn't work. - 1 quote starts the string, 2 quotes escapes and puts a quote into the string, and 1 quote closes the string.

Comment: Oh, of course. I put 5 quotes by accident. I meant to say you forgot the `@` sign.

Answer (score 9):

```
string result = myString.Replace("\"", "foo");
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. It works perfectly as you will see if you run the code.

Comment: Isn't he escaping the double quote? And so, we don't need the `@` or the double escaping.

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote, but it *might* have been downvoted because you don't indicate in your answer that the code as written won't do anything (you'd have to assign the result to something, like `myString = myString.Replace("\"", "foo");`).

Comment: No, `\"` is correct. It is that way in C-like languages to make your brain catch fire when you write string literals with quotes in them. `"My lady, I \"" + verb + "\" your dress!"`

Comment: @Dan Tao - the down-vote was removed.

Answer (score 5):

Oh, you mean you want to [replace all occurrences of the string `"` with something else](http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/string-manipulation-in-net-epilogue-plus-new-theme/)?

Try this:

```
public static class EvilStringHelper {
    private static readonly Action<string, int, char> _setChar;
    private static readonly Action<string, int> _setLength;

    static EvilStringHelper() {
        MethodInfo setCharMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(
            "SetChar",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        );

        _setChar = (Action<string, int, char>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string, int, char>), setCharMethod);

        MethodInfo setLengthMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(
            "SetLength",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        );

        _setLength = (Action<string, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string, int>), setLengthMethod);
    }

    public static void ChangeTo(this string text, string value) {
        _setLength(text, value.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; ++i)
            text.SetChar(i, value[i]);
    }

    public static void SetChar(this string text, int index, char value) {
        _setChar(text, index, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"\"".ChangeTo("Bob");
string test = string.Concat("\"", "Hello!", "\"");
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Output:

```
BobHello!Bob
```

**Note: This was totally a joke.**

Comment: ooooh. That's even snarkier than my reply. It didn't even occur to me to go so far as to use delegates and reflection.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
var st = "String with \" in it.";
st.Replace('\"', 'c'); // replacement char
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.Replace("\"", "something");
```

Comment: That won't work, should be @"\"" and the R should be uppercase

Comment: @Robert, you're right about the R, which I fixed, but not the @.

Comment: @Robert Greiner - The @ is not necessary

Comment: @Robert - with the @ you escape with double quotes instead: `Replace(@"""",//...`

Comment: Right, my mistake.  I was thinking of Regex.

Answer (score 2):

Using escape character `\`. So `"` becomes `\"` within a string

Comment: Works in C#, but not in VB.  Pity the OP didn't bother to specify what *language* he was using, as the language is way more important than the platform.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question but if escape sequences are ones you are looking for.. in this case to escape `"` then for `C#` look [here](http://rshelton.com/archive/2007/11/20/listing-of-the-c-escape-sequences---so-that-i.aspx) and for `vb.net` and comparison with C# look in the **Strings** 
section of [this](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) post.

Comment: +1 for more general answer, while avoiding flame war about @

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace a double quote with something?

If you have a string variable:

> string sMyText = ".....";

You could replace a double quote with something like this:

```
sMyText = sMyText.Replace("\"","x");
```

The slash character \ is an escape character, allowing you to use " inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

in c#
\"

or in vb.net
""

Comment: Nah...it's part of an answer.  But not extremely helpful, as it doesn't include any context.

Answer (score -1):

```
char[] str = myString.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder("");

for(int i = 0;i<str.Length;i++)
{
    if('"'.Equals(str[i])) newString.Append(''); // put your new char here
    else newString.Append(str[i]);
}

myString = newString.ToString();
str = null;

// Don't use this method. This is really stupid. I just felt like being a little snarky.
```

Comment: Seriously? A downvote for snark on a question like this? Tsk.

Comment: At least you're using `StringBuilder` and not just doing `+=` :)